# PHP combine variables and letters, eliminate spaces

Tags: php, variables

to following code:

```
$day2 = $day."T".$hours.':'.$minutes.':00';
```

Is saved to DB as

```
2012-01-30 T21:00:00
```

how can I eliminate the space between '30' and 'T' ? So it should be saved as

```
2012-01-30T21:00:00
```

Note: the $day variable doesn't contain a space at the end, so that's not the problem

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Comment: apologies $date should be $day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

very basic, maybe noobish way but i think it answers your question...

```
$day2_new = str_replace(' ', '', $day2);
```

Comment: okay, i am glad to help. you can mark my answer as accepted by clicking the tick button on the left of my answer :)

Comment: It should remove only one space between `30` and `T` as the question implies.

Answer (score 1):

For the record, `$day` does contain a space.  It **has** to.

To verify, try:

```
$day2 = rstrip($day, ' ') ."T".$hours.':'.$minutes.':00';
```

How have you verified that:

> the $day variable doesn't contain a space at the end, so that's not
>   the problem

Answer (score 0):

use the `trim()` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) in php

```
$day2 = trim($day."T".$hours.':'.$minutes.':00');
```

this will basically remove all blank spaces in your string